# Nexus user from Gradle and Jenkins (Android)

Tags: android, version-control, jenkins, gradle, nexus

I'm starting in Continuous Improvement with Jenkins, SCM, Nexus and Android-Gradle. I have a task in Gradle to upload an AAR file to my Nexus repository, and it works find if I execute it from my computer. The task is '*install*' and the gradle-code is the following:

```
// upload to our nexus repository
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        // the maven plugin features this deployer
        mavenDeployer {
            // we deploy to the release repository in this case
            repository(url: "https://nexus1.xxxxx.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases") {
                authentication(userName: getRepositoryUsername(), password: getRepositoryPassword())
            }

            // pom project information
            pom.project {
                version android.defaultConfig.versionName
                artifactId 't21-android-commons-utils'
                name 'T21 Android Commons Utils Lib'
                packaging 'aar'
            }
        }
    }
}
task install(dependsOn: uploadArchives)
```

The authentication function calls *getRepositoryUsername()* and *getRepositoryPassword()* to read credentials from *gradle.properties*. But I don't want to public this file in our SCM, it shouldn't be safe.

When I push the code to our SCM, Jenkins notices it and executes a job to do some gradle-task, including the '*install*' one. It works right but '*install*' is not able to authenticate to Nexus server because *gradle.properties* is not found (as expected).

So, I would like to know how I should do the authentication in '*install*' gradle-task from Jenkins.

I'm thinking to create a generic Jenkins-User with permissions in Nexus, but I don't know how I can call in gradle and Jenkins.

I hope to explain well. Sorry for my poor english...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I response myself.

Is possible to pass parameters to Gradle with *-Pparameter=value* and it is useful for me. I put it in Switches box in Jenkins job.

Now, credentials are in Jenkins Job but not in SCM, so the source code is clean of credentials.

Comment: You should accept your own answer if it satisfactory once you have the right to do so.